# Durandal.js document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, durandal, document-ready

How I can run my code when Durandal finishes view attach in shell.js?

I tried `viewAttached : function(){}` in my shell.js but it does not works.

All I want to do is when views loaded run some jQuery code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the view lifecycle here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks

In durandal 2.0 there is no more `viewAttached`, it has been renamed to `attached`

To Yasser - activate is happening first before viewmodel is attached to it's corresponding view so you can't access any DOM elements, attached comes after viewmodel and view are connected and you can access DOM elements

Comment: Yes, my answer was wrong, I'm going to remove that. I've forgotten the original behavior of durandal. I've applied lazy binding in my views & view models. I call applyBindings when data are loaded, therefor heavy performance improvement will occur, because of only one init, instead of one init and one update for each element on the page. thank you. That was the reason of my mistake.

Comment: Just a note, not sure if things have changed but I needed to use compositionComplete to access the DOM elements (in Firefox not sure about the others).

Comment: link is broken unless you remove the extra slash at the end.